# Xquery syntax error in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I want to return the character 'o' in my sql database while working with xml data so I wrote the following query:

```
use master 
select song_type.query ('table/[where o.name like % o %]')
from xmldata
```

but the program returned an error saying:

> Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   XQuery [xmldata.song_type.query()]: Syntax error near '[', expected a step expression.

please how do I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
select * 
from xmldata where cast(convert(varchar(max),song_type) as xml).value("o.name[0]","varchar(500)") like '% o %'
```

Comment: thanks Dhaval, but unfortunately when i executed it the program returned an error: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Explicit conversion from data type int to xml is not allowed.

Comment: Dhaval please can i send you the complete query for you to look at?

Comment: Dhaval actually what i am working on is in Xquery. that is i am trying to get a single value 'o' in my table. the system rejected the updated code and gave an error message: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'o.name'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'varchar(500)'.

Comment: Dhaval you can see the entire code and table below:

Comment: Dhaval the data type should be in xml but you specified it to be in varchar. please kindly help me!

Comment: first i convert Song_type to Varchar to remove error: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Explicit conversion from data type int to xml is not allowed so further we can cast it into Xml